# When does $n$-dimensional algebra have $m$-dimensional faithful representation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, algebras

Suppose we have an $n$-dimensional associative unital algebra $A$ over a field $k$ (assume $\operatorname{char}(k)=0$ and maybe even $k$ is closed).

> I would like to know what is the minimal possible $m$ such that it has an $m$-dimensional *faithful* representation.

Of course, $m$ is at most $n$, since any such algebra $A$ has a faithful representation $A\to End(A)$ given by left multiplication. And also it is clear that $m\geq \sqrt{n}$ by dimensional reasons.

If I remember correctly, for any finite dimensional algebra $A$ if $rad(A)$ denotes the maximal nilpotent $2$-sided ideal, then $A/rad(A)$ is a product of matrix algebras. For any matrix algebra it is clear what is such $m$. So I guess it reduces the problem to the case when for $A$ the ideal $rad(A)$ is maximal. So can we tell anything then?

I hope this is not a stupid question... I might be overlooking something very simple here.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "know." I wouldn't be surprised if this problem were undecidable for arbitrary finite-dimensional algebras.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I am not sure about the exact meaning of "know". I guess what I am looking for is some obstructions to embedability. Say, if some property of $A$ holds, then we can only embed $n$-dimensional $A$ into matrices of size $n\times n$.